How can I fix a problem with logit(expit(50)) = inf in a custom neural network model?
I am creating a custom neural network model. It is the simplest model called multi-layer perceptron (MLP).
I think there is a chain problem.

weights are some small numbers like neuron values and biases.
It sometimes makes big numbers like 50 or 100 when I add all of the neuron values that are multiplied by weights together and also add biases.
The expit() (sigmoid) of those big numbers returns exactly 1.
In the backpropagation function, I use logit() to get a derivative of neuron values. so logit(1) returns np.inf.
In the next iteration, some of these inf values multiply to negative weights and make -inf.
-inf values add to inf values that make nan.
nan  * everything = nan or nan + everything = nan so a nan is enough to make all the values of matrices, nan.

how can I fix that? Am I right about the type of problem that exists? Is there any problem with the code that I must know?
here is the code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import expit, logit, softmax


LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
TEST_DATA_AMOUNT = 0.8
EPOCHS = 20
number_of_nodes = [28 * 28, 16, 16, 10]


df = pd.read_csv("5000_records_784I_1O_mnist.csv", index_col=0)
x_data = df.iloc[:, : 28 * 28]
y_data = df.iloc[:, 28 * 28 :]
normalized_x_data = x_data / 255
x_train = normalized_x_data[
    : round(TEST_DATA_AMOUNT * len(normalized_x_data))
].to_numpy()
y_train = y_data[: round(TEST_DATA_AMOUNT * len(y_data))].to_numpy()
x_test = normalized_x_data[
    round(TEST_DATA_AMOUNT * len(normalized_x_data)) :
].to_numpy()
y_test = y_data[round(TEST_DATA_AMOUNT * len(y_data)) :].to_numpy()

NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = x_train.shape[0]

neuron_values = [np.zeros((number_of_nodes[0], 1))]
weights = []
biases = []
for i in range(1, len(number_of_nodes)):
    weights.append(np.random.rand(number_of_nodes[i], number_of_nodes[i - 1]) * 2 - 1)
    biases.append(np.random.rand(number_of_nodes[i], 1) * 2 - 1)
    neuron_values.append(np.zeros((number_of_nodes[i], 1)))

predicted_outputs = []
network_errors = []


def activate(values, activation_type):
    if activation_type == "Sigmoid":
        return expit(values)
    if activation_type == "ReLU":
        return np.maximum(values, 0)
    if activation_type == "Softmax":
        return softmax(values)
    if activation_type == "Tanh":
        return np.tanh(values)


def deactivate(values, activation_type):
    if activation_type == "Sigmoid":
        return logit(values)
    if activation_type == "ReLU":
        return values > 0
    if activation_type == "Softmax":
        return values
    if activation_type == "Tanh":
        return 1 - np.power(values, 2)


def one_hot(value):
    one_hot_value = np.zeros((10, 1))
    one_hot_value[value] = 1
    return one_hot_value


def feed_forward(inputs):
    neuron_values[0] = inputs
    for j in range(1, len(number_of_nodes) - 1):
        neuron_values[j] = activate(
            np.matmul(weights[j - 1], neuron_values[j - 1]).reshape(
                weights[j - 1].shape[0], 1
            )
            + biases[j - 1],
            "Sigmoid",
        )
    neuron_values[j + 1] = activate(
        np.matmul(weights[j], neuron_values[j]).reshape(weights[j].shape[0], 1)
        + biases[j],
        "Softmax",
    )
    return neuron_values[-1]


def back_propagate(outputs, targets, learning_rate):
    errors = []
    gradients = []
    for _ in range(1, len(number_of_nodes)):
        errors.append([])
        gradients.append([])
    errors[-1] = 2 * (outputs - targets)
    gradients[-1] = learning_rate * (errors[-1] * deactivate(outputs, "Softmax"))
    biases[-1] -= gradients[-1]
    weights[-1] -= np.matmul(gradients[-1], neuron_values[-2].T)
    for j in range(len(number_of_nodes) - 3, -1, -1):
        errors[j] = np.matmul(weights[j + 1].T, errors[j + 1])
        gradients[j] = (
            learning_rate * errors[j] * deactivate(neuron_values[j + 1], "Sigmoid")
        )
        biases[j] -= gradients[j]
        weights[j] -= np.matmul(
            gradients[j], neuron_values[j].reshape(neuron_values[j].shape[0], 1).T
        )
    return outputs - targets


def guess(inputs):
    return feed_forward(inputs)


def train(inputs, target, epochs, learning_rate):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        p = np.random.permutation(len(inputs))
        shuffled_inputs = inputs[p]
        shuffled_targets = target[p]
        for j, set_of_inputs in enumerate(shuffled_inputs):
            epoch_input = set_of_inputs
            epoch_target = shuffled_targets[j]
            outputs = feed_forward(epoch_input)
            error = back_propagate(outputs, one_hot(epoch_target), learning_rate)
            sum_of_squared_errors = np.sum(np.power(error, 2))
            network_errors.append(sum_of_squared_errors)
        # learning_rate *= 0.99
        print(
            f"Epoch #{epoch+1}: Sum of squared errors: {sum_of_squared_errors}, Target: {epoch_target}, Predict: {outputs.argmax()}"
        )


train(x_train, y_train, EPOCHS, LEARNING_RATE)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(network_errors)
plt.grid()
plt.title("Iteration Number vs Error")
plt.xlabel("Iteration Number")
plt.ylabel("Error")
plt.show()
print("Trained weights:")
for layer_weights in weights:
    print(layer_weights.shape)
    print(layer_weights)
print("Trained biases:")
for layer_biases in biases:
    print(layer_biases.shape)
    print(layer_biases)



I think you're confusing an inverse and a derivative.
The inverse of expit() is logit().
But since expit() is equivalent to the sigmoid function, the derivative of expit(x) is expit(x) * (1 - expit(x)). See this page for more details.

Thanks. I changed the deactivate function for Sigmoid function to this:
return values * (1 - values)
so that problem is fixed but now I get this as an error graph. It makes no sense
link

During the training of neural networks, you calculate gradients to update the weights. Sometimes, these gradients can become extremely large. When you use these large gradients to update your weights, it can cause the weights to grow uncontrollably, leading to very large values during the forward pass.
For instance:

If a neuron's value becomes very large (like 50 or 100), applying the sigmoid function will output a value very close to 1.
During the backpropagation, taking the logit of 1 (since the sigmoid output is ~1) can result in infinity (np.inf).
This infinity propagates through your network, corrupting gradients and weights, ultimately resulting in NaN values.

Solution: Gradient Clipping
Gradient Clipping is a technique used to prevent the gradients from becoming too large by capping them within a specified range. Think of it like controlling the flow of water through a hose to prevent it from splashing everywhere. This helps maintain numerical stability during training.
Here's how you can apply gradient clipping to your backpropagation function:
import numpy as np

def back_propagate(outputs, targets, learning_rate):
    errors = []
    gradients = []

    for _ in range(1, len(number_of_nodes)):
        errors.append([])
        gradients.append([])

    # Calculate the error for the output layer
    errors[-1] = 2 * (outputs - targets)

    # Calculate the gradient for the output layer
    gradients[-1] = learning_rate * (errors[-1] * deactivate(outputs, "Softmax"))

    # Clip the gradients to be within [-1, 1]
    gradients[-1] = np.clip(gradients[-1], -1, 1)

    # Update the biases and weights for the output layer
    biases[-1] -= gradients

